# Ubuntu and AMD's GCN 1.0 GPUs with AMDGPU-PRO 16.50 drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, fglrx, amd-graphics

I am on a debian based distribution with catalyst drivers.They work nicely but drivers crash sometimes. Also they have old software in repository. That's why I wanted to come back to Ubuntu. I left because of no support for FGLRX anymore. 
I don't like Unity and I am interested in Ubuntu Budgie right now because Budgie is  great desktop environment. I have heard that Linux 4.9 kernel is stable now and comes with a lot of support and features for AMD users. One of them is support for GCN 1.0 graphic cards. My computer specification is:
**Processor:** Intel QX6700
**GPU:** AMD R7 250X
**RAM:** 4GB
The reason why I stick to proprietary drivers is that my graphic card don't like open source drivers. There is no good hardware acceleration and everything is slow, plus video drivers crash a lot especially in KDE. So I had no choice but to install a distribution which supports installation of FGLRX.
AMDGPU-PRO 16.50 drivers have been released with some websites claiming support for GCN 1.0 drivers whereas AMD website lists only some mobile GPUs. I am confused about it. If someone with GCN 1.0 GPU has installed AMDGPU-PRO drivers, do let me know because I want to try it too. I am not a hard core gamer. I just play Xonotic or Mame games sometimes. The only reason to go for proprietary drivers is because open source drivers don't work for me.
Let me know if Ubuntu with 4.9 kernel and AMDGPU-PRO 16.50 drivers support GCN 1.0 graphic cards or at least my graphic card. I am waiting for a reply.

Answer (score 3):

New kernel 4.9 supports GCN 1.0 if you enable CIK parts in options while compiling it. I did so, and, you also have to blacklist the radeon driver, to force it to load amdgpu. Then you can install AMDGPU-PRO, but beware: You'll have to wait till it supports 4.9, right now it gives errors while compiling the module. So: AMDGPU? Yes. AMDGPU-PRO? Maybe later.
Might be helpful:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU#Enable_amdgpu_for_Sea_Islands_or_Southern_Islands_cards

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)